# How can I remove duplicate objects with distinctBy from a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How can I use `distinctBy` on a list of custom objects to strip out the duplicates? I want to determine "uniqueness" by multiple properties of the object, but not all of them.

I was hoping something like this would work, but no luck:

`val uniqueObjects = myObjectList.distinctBy { it.myField, it.myOtherField }`

Edit: I'm curious how to use `distinctBy` with any number of properties, not just two like in my example above.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can create a pair:

```
myObjectList.distinctBy { Pair(it.myField, it.myOtherField) }
```

The `distinctBy` will use equality of `Pair` to determine uniqueness.

Comment: Or even just `it.myField to it.myOtherField`.

Comment: Thanks, but how about if I need to compare four, five, or more properties?

Comment: And to compare more values, you can use `.distinctBy { listOf(...) }`

Comment: There is also another non-idiomatic way - override `equals` and `hashCode` and compare only few fields which are needed to determine duplicate and then use simple `distinct()`

Comment: is there any "in place" idea for `MutableList` to distinct by ?

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the implementation of the `distinctBy`, it just adds the value you pass in the lambda to a `Set`. And if the `Set` did not already contain the specified element, it adds the respective item of the original `List` to the new `List` and that new `List` is being returned as the result of `distinctBy`.

```
public inline fun <T, K> Iterable<T>.distinctBy(selector: (T) -> K): List<T> {
    val set = HashSet<K>()
    val list = ArrayList<T>()
    for (e in this) {
        val key = selector(e)
        if (set.add(key))
            list.add(e)
    }
    return list
}
```

So you can pass a composite object that holds the properties that you require to find the uniqueness.

```
data class Selector(val property1: String, val property2: String, ...)
```

And pass that `Selector` object inside the lambda:

```
myObjectList.distinctBy { Selector(it.property1, it.property2, ...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a triple:

```
myObjectList.distinctBy { Triple(it.firstField, it.secondField, it.thirdField) }
```

The `distinctBy` will use equality of `Triple` to determine uniqueness.

*I have implemented in this way, it provides most Unique list