# How can we remove similar items in a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, syntax

Do we have any specific Function to do that or we can use the normal for-loop logic
Eg:-

```
// we have a list, say carList, which is initially empty 
val carList = mutableListOf<Cars>()
carList.add(randomCar()) // adding any random car
// so I want to know that , if there is any duplicate entry, how can I remove it from carList ?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883719/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-objects-with-distinctby-from-a-list-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by converting the list into a set or by using the distinct function.

Here's a reference: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure there are no duplication, then I suggest to use `set` instead of `list`. Using list for such usage would be more complex by requiring extra looping, checking and removal. Be aware that any comparison between two elements is based on implementations of methods `equals` and `hashCode` (Kotlin data class provide such functionality out of box by implementing these functions for you).

Comment: only need to add two line " Cars car=randomCar();if(! carList.contains(car)){carList.add(car);}. Add this, same data will not add in list.

Answer (score 0):

There's `list.contains(...)`. You can check for the existence of the variable and if it exists, run the Random Generator again. Or if you wish to just remove the previous item then add this same one, or whatever you know. There's `removeFilter` too, if you wish to achieve something more complex, but this is not what I think will be required for your use case.

Thanks